# How to handle a POST request error using XMLHttpRequest() and Javascript

Tags: javascript, http, post, error-handling, request

I am trying to handle an error thrown by a HTTP request, but am unable to properly intercept the event.

> POST http://localhost:8080/path/to/endpoint 500 (Internal Server Error)

I have a drop zone on the page that receives a file and parses it on a server. When the file is properly formatted it works well, but am trying to handle errors caused by improperly formatted documents.

According to the Mozilla docs the XMLHttpRequest has an onerror function, but it's getting bypassed when I try to use it as follows:

```
_postRequest() {
  let files = this.files[0];
  let data = new FormData();
  let request = new XMLHttpRequest();

  // File selected by the user - in case of multiple files append each of them
  data.append('file', this.files[0]);

  // AJAX request finished
  request.addEventListener('load', (e) => {
    // Send response to DOM
    this.dispatchEvent(new CustomEvent('return-validated-items', {
      bubbles: true, composed: true,
      detail: request.response
    }));
  });

  // If server is sending a JSON response then set JSON response type
  request.responseType = 'json';

  // Send POST request to the server side script
  request.open('post', 'http://localhost:8080/path/to/endpoint');
  request.onerror = function () { // This function is not working properly
    console.log("** An error occurred during the transaction");
  };
  request.send(data);
}
```

I was also having issues with this alternative method:

```
try {
  request.open('post', 'http://localhost:8080/path/to/endpoint');
  request.send(data);
} catch (e) {
  console.log(e)
}
```

How can I handle an error caused by `request.send()`?

Comment: The short answer is, make sure the server sends something back. Afaik, the `onerror` part is there to handle client-side errors (no network connection, host unreachable, etc.).

Comment: It's an internal server error and as best I can tell Express is sending back `res.status(500).send(err.message)`. What do you mean by "make sure the server sends something back?"

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The load event should get the message. Look at the status there

```
request.addEventListener('load', (e) => {
  console.log(e.currentTarget.status) // or request.status
})
```

so you can do something like

```
request.addEventListener('load', (e) => {
  if (request.status < 400) {
    dispatchIt()
  } else {
    displayError()
  }
})
```